# Can't fin .NET 5 in Azure

Tags: .net, azure

I'm upgrading a web app in Azure to .NET 5, but can't find it in the portal. Do I have to do something before it is accessible?

There is only .NET 5 (Early access)

[image]
[Azure App General settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKWQL.png)

Comment: What is the issue with Early access?

Comment: There's suppose to be a .NET 5 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/announcing-asp-net-core-in-net-5/

Comment: uhm... if you read a little more you'll find that Early Access will allow to use not only .NET 5 ... (somewhere after *Deploy .NET 5 Web Apps to Azure App Service Today*)

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Extension on portal to use `.Net 5.0`.

[image]

**Post**

[Can't execute .net 5 program as Azure WebJob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296915/cant-execute-net-5-program-as-azure-webjob/65299413#65299413)

**Blog**

[Run .NET 5 on Azure App Services](https://kontext.tech/column/cloud-azure/520/run-net-5-on-azure-app-services)